# Transform MKAnnotationView without Callout

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I try to scale up the view of a MKAnnotation on
 `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)`
As you can see in the animation, the problem is that not only the Pin part of the MKAnnotation, but also is the Callout is scaled - anybody knows how to fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

I use the following code for the scaling animation (it's an extension for UIView)

```
func scaleUp(duration: TimeInterval = 0.2) {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: { () -> Void in
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
    }) { (animationCompleted: Bool) -> Void in }
}
```

Comment: Instead of scaling the view with a transform, increase the size of the annotation's _image_?

Comment: It's an extension for UIView - I have updated the question

Comment: @matt thanks for the idea. It seems that MKAnnotationView don't use an UIImageView to display the image, so I cannot access .transform

Comment: No, but it does have an `image`. I didn't say anything about UIImageView, and I specifically advised _against_ using the transform.

Comment: And here's another idea: for the existing annotation, substitute another annotation with a bigger image that you have scaled _down_ with `transform` to the same size as the first one, and scale it _up_ — to 100%. Now the callout will be normal.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the callout view is `MKAnnotationView`'s subview. Unfortunately you can't access the callout view hence there is no way to counter that transformation - Well you could find the callout view in the hierarchy, but it doesn't work as you would need.

But you could approach it from the opposite direction:

- **Start with lower scale** *(this will act as the default size)*, let's say `0.5`, and scale it up to `1.0` *(in this moment u have selected pin with standard size callout view)*.
- All you need is proper sized image for the default value *(in this case the default image size must be bigger)*.

## If you're using clustering:

The MapKit framework internally changes the transformation matrix for the translation purpose *(The pin is moving to/from the cluster)*. This has one side effect, it changes `a` and `d` in the transformation matrix to `1.0` which means it resets the scale you set previously. To solve that, override the transform in the annotation view like so:

```
override var transform: CGAffineTransform {
    get {
        return super.transform
    }
    set {
        super.transform = CGAffineTransform(
            a: isSelected ? 1.0 : 0.5,
            b: newValue.b,
            c: newValue.c,
            d: isSelected ? 1.0 : 0.5,
            tx: newValue.tx,
            ty: newValue.ty)
    }
}
```